# How to define swig typmap for wchar_t to bind with Perl scripts?

Tags: perl, swig

I am using [SWIG](http://swig.org/) to call C++ functions from Perl scripts. Thre is no problem when I pass `char*` in a Perl script like the following:

```
AddValue(char* val)
```

but I cannot write the same for `wchar_t` like:

```
AddValue(wchar_t* val)
```

because there is no SWIG typemap defined for this datatype. SWIG delivers a `perlstrings.swg` typemap which does the conversion for `char*`. I need something similar for `wchar_t*`. Any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The wchar_t implementation for Python is present in `pywstrings.swg` and is only 60+ lines.  Given that, `perlstrings.swg` as a Perl code example and a bounty you might get someone to port it for you :)

Comment: thank you for the comment. I know about pywstrings.swg and it

Comment: thank you for the comment. I know about pywstrings.swg and it is fine. however the techniques used there has nothing really to do with Perl. The problem here is actually handling unicode data with Perl which I need help with.